# shell scripting: get a specified range of parameters

Tags: shell

I normally come here if google doesnt work. So this time it goes like this:
In a function, i want to assign  to a variable from the 4-th input parameter onward. 
Example:

```
function foo {  
  var="$4$5$6..."   
  use var  
  commands using $1, etc  
}
```

So i think i cannot use shift, since i want to use $1 afterwards. I do not either want to use an extra var to store $1,$2,$3 and shift. So how should it work?

Comment: "I do not either want to use an extra var to store $1,$2,$3 and shift".  Bad idea.  What's wrong with this?  It's how the shell is supposed to work.  Why reject the simple, obvious, and correct solution?

Comment: To 'jamessan': $1, etc appear much behind where i need the 'var' and $1, etc are used only once later. So i am trying to save the effort to explicitly store them. (Imagine it is not 4 in this case, but 10, then i will need to store 9 times.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
function foo {
    var=${@:4}
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone wanted a version without bashisms? Okay, but you won't like it.

```
#!/bin/sh

do_something () {
        i=4
        var=
        while [ $i -lt 10 ] ; do
                tmp=
                eval tmp=\"'$'$i\"
                if [ -z "$tmp" ] ; then
                        break
                else
                        var="$var$tmp"
                fi
                i=$(($i+1))
        done
        echo $var
}

do_something one two three four five six "six and a half" seven eight nine
```

I tested this with dash and FreeBSD's sh, but I cannot really guarantee the portability of evaling things. I also had to limit it to parameters $1 to $9, since after that it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

*Additionally to Alex answer:*

All arguments but the last:

```
var=${@:1:${#}-1}
```

The last argument:

```
var=${@:${#}}  

or POSIX:
eval var=\${{#}}
```